# Trigger an API automatically based on user specified time using nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-services, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an application which will trigger a http api based on user specified time. Basically it is a message scheduling app on Nodejs that will call different web-services to communicate and post data on user specified time. I am using AWS dynamo db to store user messages and date & time when they want to publish. 
What will be the best solution to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While there are tons of ways to solve this problem, I think the cleaner solution would be with

Dynamodb (Table with TTL field) --> DynamoDBStreams (Old Image) -->  (Check for Remove Record) Lambda (do whatever you want with the event here)

Create a record in DynamoDB with a TTL field that you want to trigger your record. Stream will deliver a record removed stream message which can be received by the lambda and you can take any action from there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I do not want to remove records from db.. because I want to show the list of items which has been scheduled.

Comment: You can insert the records back again to a different table. It is a scalable way for time based triggers, that we use.

Comment: How to trigger an api call at the time of TTL expires?
Is there any alternate solution apart from using the dynamodb streams/TTL?

Comment: Event will be delivered to Lambda. You need to write Lambda to handle whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the timestamp of data post and the end points in DynamoDB and use an [Lambda Schedule Event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) that checks the records frequently to query and post the data.

You can store timestamp as a sortkey so that it can be queried comparing with the current timestamp.

Note: One of the challenges with the DynamoDB TTL approach is that the timestamp to post the data(at TTL value) can vary up to 48 hours. According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html)

> DynamoDB typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of
>   expiration. The exact duration within which an item truly gets deleted
>   after expiration is specific to the nature of the workload and the
>   size of the table.